# Android SDK keeps installing installed SDKs

Tags: android, sdk

When I open the Android SDK Manager, a screen appears "Choose Packages to Install".  It lists a bunch of packages with green checkmarks (which are already installed), and some with x's, which are not installed.  If I choose "Accept All", it re-downloads and installs the packages that are already installed and says it installs the others, but when I restart afterwards, I am back to the same result.

Am I doing something wrong?

Machine: Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. If I recall this didn't used to happen at least in the SDK Manager revision 12 (I didn't update until now, revision 16).

In the past I think the popup used to show new/updates only, which was the way it should be. But now it keeps showing the same packages even when it's already installed. I submitted a bug Issue for it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23222

Right now I just ignore and cancel out of the popup and rely only on the actual SDK Manager homescreen to see which packages are new or need updating. Seems to work.